# WebSecurity.CurrentUserName returning username from other session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.Net MVC WebSecurity.

Wondering how I make sure that WebSecurity.CurrentUserName returns user name of the current session. 
I have seen a login code like before and I have a doubt on the session variable.

Should I put unique value for each sesionPlaceholder? Will it resolve my problem.

Thanks.

```
 public bool Login(string username, string password)
    {
        // Validate credentials
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            return false;

        bool credentialsAreValid = WebSecurity.Login(username, password);
        if (credentialsAreValid)
        {
            // Must add object to session in order to create a _persistent_ session id
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("sessionPlaceholder", "");
        }
        return credentialsAreValid;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this we will discuss about the ASP.NET Roles and Membership API from MVC perspective. We will try to see how the default Roles and Membership provides can be used for authentication and authorization in an MVC application. We will also see how we can implement custom forms authentication in an ASP.NET MVC application.

### [A Beginner's Tutorial on Custom Forms Authentication in ASP.NET MVC Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-27splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF)